# Unexpected/Forced Termination of process due to dll ejection

Tags: python, winapi, dll

I injected a DLL I wrote into another process using CreateRemoteThread function and it works great.
but when I try to eject the DLL using the same method, it causes the process to terminate and I dont understands why.

Here is the function that I wrote to eject the DLL:

```
def EjectDLL(processId, dllPath):
    hThread  = None

    hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD,
                                     False, processId)
    if hProcess == None:
        CleanUp(hProcess, None, hThread)
        return False

    for module in EnumProcessModules(processId):
        if module[0].lower() == dllPath.lower():
            threadRtn = kernel32.GetProcAddress(kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "FreeLibraryA")
            if threadRtn == None:
                break

            hThread = kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, None, 0, threadRtn, module[1], 0, None)
            if hThread == None:
                break

            kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE)      #wait for remote thread to finish

            CleanUp(hProcess, None, hThread)
            return True

    CleanUp(hProcess, None, hThread)
    return False
```

EnumProcessModules yields a tuple where the first index is the path of the module and the second index is HMODULE of the module.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no function in `kernel32.dll` called `FreeLibraryA`, only `FreeLibrary`, so your call to `GetProcAddress` is returning null.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt notice I added an A. since every win32 application must have kernel32.dll, and the system maps this dll to the same address in every process, there shouldnt be any problem using the GetModuleHandle.